# Derivation of runtime for triple nested for loop

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o, nested-loops

I had to do a problem which required me to figure out the runtime for this snippet of code:

```
for (i = 1; i <= log(n); i = i + 1) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 2*i; j = 2*j) {
        for (k = 1; k <= log(j); k = k + 1) {
            print("[some arbitrary string]");
        }
    }
}
```

It is obvious by inspection that this is `Θ((log(n)^3)`, since each of the `for` loops is `Θ(log(n))`, but I'm not exactly sure what the best way to rigorously prove this is (using sums, for example).

Comment: use tree to prove complexity.

Comment: I'm not even sure that every loop is `O(lg n)`.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, it's not 2^i it's 2*i. I mistyped it

Answer (score 2):

Let's substitute `log(n)` with `x` (`x = log(n)`). Then

```
for (i = 1; i <= x; i = i + 1) {
    for (j = 1; j <= 2*i; j = 2*j) {
        for (k = 1; k <= log(j); k = k + 1) {
            print("[some arbitrary string]");
        }
    }
}
```

In the second loop `j` runs through powers of `2`. Let's take another loop with same asymptotics using another substitution: `y = log(j)`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= x; i = i + 1) {
    for (y = 0; y <= log(i); ++y) {
        for (k = 1; k <= y; k = k + 1) {
            print("[some arbitrary string]");
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity is `O(x * log(x)^2) = O(log(n) * log(log(n))^2)`.

Comment: Since `log(a^2) = 2log(a)`, your result can be simplified to `O(log(n)*log(log(n))`.

Comment: @LeandroCaniglia But `log(x)^2` is not `log(x^2)`.